# Derive a formula to get the particular value from table

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have a table of points earned given the final game score.

```
Min Score   Max Score   Points
--------------------------------------
   0             999             0
 1000            1499           30
 1500            1999           40
 2000            2999           60
 3000            3999           80
 4000            4999          100
 5000            5999          120
 6000            6999          140
 7000            7999          160
 8000            8999          180
 9000            9999          200
10000            10999         220
11000            11999         240
12000            12999         260
13000            13999         280
14000            14999         300
15000            >15k          320
```

The points are awarded after the game depending on your final score. 
i.e if you score 9000 you get 200 points.
Any score above 15000 gets 320 points(Thats the maximum points awarded).
Can anyone derive a formula that can calculate the points given the final score?

Answer (score 0):

If the score is greater or equal to $2000$, then I believe the players get $\frac{\text{round(score)}}{1000}\cdot 20 + 20$ points, where $\text{round(score)}$ means the value of $\text{score}$, rounded to the bottom $1000$ (that score can be expressed by `score - (score % 1000)`, where `%` means the $\text{mod}$ operator.

For the scores below $2000$, I can't see an easy way to describe them, but there are only $3$ cases to deal with so you can treat them separately.

A quasi-program that would calculate the scores would then be

```
if score < 1000:
    points = 0
else if score < 1500:
    points = 30
else if score < 16000:
    points = floor(score) * 0.02 + 20
else:
    score = 320
```

Comment: this formula works for certain scores only, can it be modified to work with any score? be it 10, 2000, 700, 50500,... and still give the correct points?

Comment: Well, the formula works for scores from $2000$ up to $14999$. For other values, just handle those cases individually.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of how to calculate. I don't really think you can describe the points any more densely.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, i have tested your formula `p=floor(score)*0.02 +20` for values between 2000 and 14999 but i keep getting the wrong answers. have u tested with the score being 2090, 3900,10200,...

Comment: `floor(2090) = 2000`, meaning `floor(2090) * 0.02 + 20 = 2000 * 0.02 + 20 = 40 + 20 = 60`. Where is the problem? Same with `3000`, where `floor(3900) = 3000` and `3000 * 0.02 + 20 = 60 + 20 = 80`...

Comment: am sorry but all this time i thought `floor(x)` is the largest integer not greater than x . Which makes `floor(2090)= 2090`, i now get u.
lets try get a formula for the less than 2000 scores

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant the "custom" floor I defined at the beginning in my question, sorry.